# Rest/Json Api provided by Allauth Views

Tags: ios, django, facebook, django-allauth

I am using Django allauth in a variety of application that I make and its awesome!

Right now, I am trying to develop a login process in two separate steps.
I have a client (mobile) social login with some provider (twitter, Facebook) and the client takes the oauth credentials and sends them back to the server.

That means, that I do not need to use the forms and the templates provided, since all that are handled just fine by the client already.
What I need, is to know what functions/views I need to call in order to avoid all the functions that need the request to work properly.

I hope that I explained in detail my issue.